# Pineスクリプトのツールバーでの"新規作成"の消滅

Tags: pine-script

TradingViewのPineスクリプトについて質問があります。
Pineスクリプトの"チャートに追加"などのコマンドがあるツールバーに関して，
私が使ってるTradingViewのPineスクリプト内に"新規作成"と"オープン"のコマンドが存在しません。
インターネットとかで紹介されているほかの方のそれには2つのコマンドが存在しています。
この原因がわかる方はご教示お願い致します。

Comment: TradingView[利用規約、ポリシー、免責事項](https://jp.tradingview.com/policies/)の「15. TradingViewへのフィードバック」によると「お問い合わせや[フィードバック](https://www.reddit.com/r/TradingView/)のウェブページ」というのがあるようなので、そちらに問い合わせてはどうでしょう？ あるいは日本語の[ヘルプセンター](https://jp.tradingview.com/support/)でしょうか？ Pineスクリプトユーザーマニュアルの最後 [Where can I get more information?](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Where_can_I_get_more_information.html) に [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pine-script) が出てきますが、その示す先は英語版のサイトであり、そちらの活動は活発なようですが、日本語のStackOverflowサイトで同様のサポートが行われているようには見えません。

Comment: こちらのサイトにはコミュニティが小さくてなかなか回答が集まらないかもしれませんが、少なくとも質問文の中にバージョンの情報が無いと答えにくいかなと思いました。あるいはスクリーンショットなどがあると問題が分かりやすくなりそうです。

Answer (score 0):

チャートに追加の左の保存のさらに左の開くの中にあります。
もしなかったら再インストールが早いかもしれませんね。